# In main method call scale on rect with value 10 and print the rectangle area afterwards

Tags: java, scale

I am using an java AIDE app and have been asked to complete the task as stated in my question.

Every time I run my code the app tells me "the program should print the area of the rectangle after scaleing."

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, please see code below: ....p.s I am still not 100% sure what scaleing means if anyone could explain I would really appreciate it. Thanks

```
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 200);
        System.out.println(rect.getWidth());
        System.out.println(rect.getHeight());


    rect.setWidth(10);
    rect.setHeight(20);
    rect.scale(10);
System.out.println(rect.getArea());


}
}

class Rectangle
{
int width;
int height;
int factor;


Rectangle(int width, int height) 
    {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    }

void setHeight(int height)
{
    this.height = height;
}

void setWidth(int width)
{
    this.width = width;
}

int getWidth()
{
    return this.width;
}

int getHeight()
{
    return this.height;
}

void scale(int factor)
{
width = width * factor;
height = height * factor;
}

int getArea()
{
return this.width * this.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code appears to work for me with the output below.  Are you sure that you're running the compiled `Main` class from your IDE?

```
100
200
20000
```

Comment: I think error is with the AIDE you can't pass this exam lol

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your `java AIDE app`, but I found that you've initialized `rect` with `(100, 200)`, and then you reset it to `(10, 20)`, so is it possible that your app consider its a `scale of 0.1`? Maybe you should *print the area* after that change, I guesss.

Answer (score 0):

You just need write `rect.scale(10);
        System.out.println(rect.getArea());`
at the new line like to this one

```
    public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 200);
        System.out.println(rect.getWidth());
        System.out.println(rect.getHeight());


    rect.setWidth(10);
    rect.setHeight(20);
System.out.println(rect.getArea());

    rect.scale(10);
System.out.println(rect.getArea());


}
}
```

,where

```
rect.scale(10);
    System.out.println(rect.getArea());
```

are separated.